# Queue to ConcurrentQueue

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, queue, backgroundworker

I have a regular Queue object in C# (4.0) and I'm using BackgroundWorkers that access this Queue.

The code I was using is as follows:

```
   do
    {
        while (dataQueue.Peek() == null // nothing waiting yet 
            && isBeingLoaded == true // and worker 1 still actively adding stuff
        )
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

        // otherwise ready to do something: 
        if (dataQueue.Peek() != null) // because maybe the queue is complete and also empty 
        {
            string companyId = dataQueue.Dequeue();
            processLists(companyId);
            // use up the stuff here //
        } // otherwise nothing was there yet, it will resolve on the next loop.
    } while (isBeingLoaded == true // still have stuff coming at us 
           || dataQueue.Peek() != null);   // still have stuff we haven’t done
```

However, I guess when dealing with threads I should be using a `ConcurrentQueue`.
I was wondering if there were examples of how to use a `ConcurrentQueue` in a Do While Loop like above?

Everything I tried with the TryPeek wasn't working..

Any ideas?

Comment: Tell us more about the concurrency situation: What thread is running your posted code? What are the other threads doing? Which threads write to which variables?

Comment: Are you using 1 producer and 1 consumer?

Comment: "Everything I tried with the TryPeek wasn't working.."  It wasn't working  in what way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) as a producer-consumer queue.

My answer makes some assumptions about your architecture, but you can probably mold it as you see fit:

```
public void Producer(BlockingCollection<string> ids)
{
    // assuming this.CompanyRepository exists
    foreach (var id in this.CompanyRepository.GetIds())
    {
        ids.Add(id);
    }

    ids.CompleteAdding(); // nothing left for our workers
}

public void Consumer(BlockingCollection<string> ids)
{
    while (true)
    {
       string id = null;
       try
       {
           id = ids.Take();
       } catch (InvalidOperationException) {
       }

       if (id == null) break;

       processLists(id);
    }
}
```

You could spin up as many consumers as you need:

```
var companyIds = new BlockingCollection<string>();
Producer(companyIds);

Action process = () => Consumer(companyIds);

// 2 workers
Parallel.Invoke(process, process);
```

Comment: I guess this is what the OP needs. He might *want* something different but this is what he needs.

Comment: I was able to modify this, to my structure (While trying to understand it).  I did see pretty significant improvement with performance.

Comment: +1. Out of interest, I believe the `while(true)` could be simplified with an `foreach` iteration over the `BlockingCollection`'s [GetConsumingEnumerable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx)

Comment: @StuartLC: yep, provided he only had one consumer.